# Can't get nodeJS Express post to display body data

Tags: node.js, express, http-post, httprequest

I feel like I've tried everything, would appreciate some fresh eyes to look upon my problem. As the title suggests, I'm sending a http post request to my NodeJS server that is running express, and nodeJS returns the `req.body` to be undefined/empty.

NodeJS Express Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
 Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
});

app.post('/addComment', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

Javascript Browser Code:

```
let data = {name: 'aName'};

fetch('http://localhost:5000/addComment', {
 method: 'post',
 body: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `body-parser` middleware :

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
app.post('/addComment', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

see [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Comment: I did try this, my console log only spits out: {}

Comment: Nevermind, thank you. I'd forgotten to add the content-type in the http request.

Response was much appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest express, you can actually use do

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.use(express.json()) 
    app.use (express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
       Content-Type, Accept");
       next();
   });

   app.post('/addComment', (req, res) => {
       console.log(req.body);
   });

   app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

Express now bundle body-parser by default due to popular demand.

Comment: Did try this, console log only spits out: {}

Comment: Nevermind, thank you. I'd forgotten to add the content-type in the http request.

Response was much appriciated.